# How to achieve change style for a class in Salesforce trailhead

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce-lightning

I am having an issue while trying to add style to a particular class in trailhead salesforce. I tried with all the below things but no luck.

```
document.body.style.setWidth = 100%;
document.getElementsByClassName("overlay").setWidth = 100%;
document.querySelectorAll(".overlay").setWidth = 100%;
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = 100%;
```

What would be the best thing to add style when the event happened in trailhead salesforce.

Comment: In the first line, `100%` is not a valid String. You need to wrap the value in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think 100% should be a string. Try `"100%"` instead of 100%. Also try `width` instead of setWidth.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line, the left-hand of the assignment is correct, but you need to wrap the right-hand assigned value in quotes.

A percentage value is not a valid type in JavaScript. It needs to be either a `Number` or a `String` type. You are confusing the values in a CSS file with JavaScript values.

```js
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = '100%'; // Override CSS
```

```css
#sideNav {
  width: 64px; /* Default */
  height: 64px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideNav"></div>
```

Comment: sry, I have written wrong in here but actually I was passing 100% as string in quotes.